# Parent component not resizing to fit children

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a `<div className="canvas">` element that contains four `<div className="stripe stripe-color">` elements that I will be styling dynamically adding random color classes.

I want to use this `canvas` element as a 'dynamic background'.

As you can see, I have a `<div className="children">{props.children}</div>` element among the `<div className="stripe"/>` elements:

```
const Canvas = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="stripe-container">
      <div className="children">{props.children}</div>
      <div className="stripe stripe-yellow" />
      <div className="stripe stripe-green" />
      <div className="stripe stripe-red" />
      <div className="stripe stripe-purple" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And SCSS:

```
.stripe-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.children {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 6vw);
}

.stripe-yellow {
  background: #fdc111;
}

.stripe-green {
  background: #00ad5e;
}

.stripe-red {
  background: #d33136;
}

.stripe-purple {
  background: #8f3192;
}
```

The problem here is that `<div className="canvas">` won't grow to fit the children's height so if the content in `<div className="children">{props.children}</div>` becomes too large or if the user uses a smaller viewport, the children will overflow into the height and allow you to scroll, but `canvas` won't expand to fit it's children.

As additional information, `props.children` is a React component that contains a list of "card elements" for a restaurant's menu. The cards and its container use `flex` to wrap around if they don't have enough space horizontally. This is causing the canvas to become too small on smaller  viewports. `height:100%` and their variants won't work either.

Any ideas into how I can get the desired behavior? I'm also open to refactoring as long as my requirement of achieving dynamic color stripes remains.

Here's a minima reproducible example without React:

```css
.stripe-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.children {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 6vw);
}

.stripe {
  height: 100%
}

.stripe-yellow {
  background: #fdc111;
}

.stripe-green {
  background: #00ad5e;
}

.stripe-red {
  background: #d33136;
}

.stripe-purple {
  background: #8f3192;
}

.child-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background: lightgray;
  opacity: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe-container">
  <div class="children">
    <div class="child-container">
      <div class="child">one</div>
      <div class="child">two</div>
      <div class="child">three</div>
      <div class="child">four</div>
      <div class="child">five</div>
      <div class="child">six</div>
      <div class="child">seven</div>
      <div class="child">eight</div>
      <div class="child">nine</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stripe stripe-yellow"></div>
  <div class="stripe stripe-red"></div>
  <div class="stripe stripe-green"></div>
  <div class="stripe stripe-purple"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the way absolute positioning works. You've pulled the children out of the normal flow. (out of the grid).

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that if I don't have set their position as absolute, the strips will not work as a background. How can I make an element with stripes act as a background? Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need "stacking context" (to enable z-index) position needs to be relative. In addition, you should consider [fit-content()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content)

Comment: Creating a [example] will make it easier for someone to help you.

Comment: I agree Randy, I just added a minimal reproducible example and it behaves just like I described. How can we make the container and stripes to match the height of the children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()) for the striped background? You could accomplish what you're trying to do with simpler CSS and without the extraneous markup.

Optional: If you declared [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) for the stripe colors you could change them simply by setting different values instead of having to rewrite the gradient each time (although the gradient itself isn't complicated or particularly verbose anyway.)

```css
:root {
  /*
    Using custom properties here to demonstrate
    that you could control the stripe colors without
    hard-coding them in the stylesheet. an element
    could declare its own colors via another class
    or even an inline style, e.g.
    <div style="--stripe-1: blue">
    This isn't required. Just a suggestion.
  */
  --stripe-1: #fdc111; /* yellow */
  --stripe-2: #00ad5e; /* green */
  --stripe-3: #d33136; /* red */
  --stripe-4: #8f3192; /* purple */
}

.container {
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    var(--stripe-1) 0 25%,
    var(--stripe-2) 25% 50%,
    var(--stripe-3) 50% 75%,
    var(--stripe-4) 75%
  );
  
}

.container > * {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background: lightgray;
  opacity: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
  <div>five</div>
  <div>six</div>
  <div>seven</div>
  <div>eight</div>
  <div>nine</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand 100% what you're trying to achieve. But I'll try my best to help you.

Removing the `absolute` from the `children` and putting it on the `stripes` instead might do the trick. Additionally, you'll want to position the `stripes` on 25% of the width to the left respectively.

I don't think you need CSS `grid` for this anymore, so I removed it and added some small tweaks as well. Let me know if you have any questions or if I got the question wrong.

```css
.stripe-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3vw;
  position: relative;
}

.children {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
}

.stripe {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.stripe-yellow {
  left: 0;
  background: #fdc111;
}

.stripe-green {
  left: 25%;
  background: #00ad5e;
}

.stripe-red {
  left: 50%;
  background: #d33136;
}

.stripe-purple {
  left: 75%;
  background: #8f3192;
}

.child-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  background: lightgray;
  opacity: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe-container">
  <div class="children">
    <div class="child-container">
      <div class="child">one</div>
      <div class="child">two</div>
      <div class="child">three</div>
      <div class="child">four</div>
      <div class="child">five</div>
      <div class="child">six</div>
      <div class="child">seven</div>
      <div class="child">eight</div>
      <div class="child">nine</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stripe stripe-yellow"></div>
  <div class="stripe stripe-red"></div>
  <div class="stripe stripe-green"></div>
  <div class="stripe stripe-purple"></div>
</div>
```

This way, the stripes work as a background for the stripe-container no matter the size, and since the children element is no longer absolute, the container is finally able to have the same size as the children.